# In Integration Services Catalogs getting "Cannot access a disposed object." error

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2016

In Integration Services Catalogs I configured parameters of the project and pressed OK and then again when I am going to change the parameter configurations by right clicking on project and clicking on configure it gives me below error.

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'TaskFormDialogHost'. (System.Windows.Forms)
```

And I am not able to access any properties of the project.

Is there any way to get the project back?

Answer (score 14):

I just ran into this myself after changing the current version of a project. I just closed SQL Server Management Studio and opened it back up. I was then able to switch the version back to what it was before.